# How can I display Graphics from API Data to Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've never used Umbraco, and my boss asked me to search for an ASP.NET CMS, but one of the main features of the site I'm going to develop is showing some graphics based on some data (charts and stuff like that). I thought I could just import an ASP.NET page with the code to show the charts, but I don't even know if that's possible. I would love to get any advise or suggestion.

Comment: 'some graphics based on some data'. You kind of have to be a little more precise about what you're actually trying to do. The chart could as well be an image and have a media picker in Umbaco to show it on the View.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, what Im trying to do on Umbraco is to show statistics, let's say for exaple on how much of selected products have been selling in the past month. Im looking for a way to show that data using charts

Comment: Where's that data available? Is it in a database? Coming from an API on request? Or something different? Umbraco by default doesn't have a 'charts' editor but there's probably a good solution out there. You said 'import an asp.net with the code to show the charts'. Have in mind that no matter what asp.net CMS you use or maybe it's just mvc, you'll still have to use js to create the graphs. ASP.NET is not made for styling.